# Composer debug dependencies

Tags: php, debugging, composer-php, mailgun

I should figure out, how to debug such situations?

I try to send mail throw Mailgun package.

How to figure out why the class is not found? `Error: Class 'Mailgun\Messages\MessageBuilder' not found in /vendor/boundstate/yii2-mailgun/Message.php:239`
but IDE shows me that class exist in package `mailgun/mailgun-php`

Take a look on a slice of composer.json:

```
    "boundstate/yii2-mailgun": "0.0.4",
    "Mailgun/Mailgun-php": "^1.0",
```

ADD:

I have required autoload.php Also, composer use psr4. I see the correct path to classes. Take a look:

```
    'boundstate\\mailgun\\' => array($vendorDir . '/boundstate/yii2-mailgun'),
    'Mailgun\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mailgun/mailgun-php/src'),
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, such things happen when you didn't require `vendor/autoload.php`, or autoload wasn't generated. IDE may show you that everything is OK just because it parsed your composer.json.

Try to:

1. composer update
2. get sure you required vendor/autoload.php in your script

Comment: I have required autoload. Also, composer use psr4. I see the correct path to classes. Take a look:  'boundstate\\mailgun\\' => array($vendorDir . '/boundstate/yii2-mailgun'), 'Mailgun\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mailgun/mailgun-php/src'),

Comment: Here is no need to add your composer libs with `autoload` section of composer.json file. It should work out of box.

Comment: yes, I know it. I need to figure out why is not wokring out of box?

Comment: Ok, understood... Hm. Is that the local environment or do you do it on a remote one?

Comment: remote environment

Comment: Have you run ‘composer update’ via ssh on remote one?